# Recursive iteration from json data to tree

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to iterate through json object and build a treeview structure through a hierarchical structered object.
 I have the following code but i dont get FFF and GGG nodes. Any ideas please ?

```
    var html = {
    ul: '<ul></ul>',
    li: '<li></li>',
    span: '<span></span>'
};

function TreeView(jobj) {
    var node = jobj.data[0].Nodes[0];
    var $ul_root = $(html.ul),
        $li_root = $(html.li);
    var $span = $(html.span);
    $span.text(node.Key);
    $li_root.append($span);
    $ul_root.append($li_root);
    $.each(node.Nodes, function (i, n) {
        var $ul_parent = $(html.ul),
            $li_parent = $(html.li);
        var $span = $(html.span);
        $span.text(n.Key);
        $li_parent.append($span);
        $ul_parent.append($li_parent);
        $li_root.append($ul_parent);
        recursive(n.Nodes, $li_parent);
    })
    return $ul_root;

    function recursive(TreeNodes, $li_parent) {
          if (TreeNodes.length > 0) {
              var $ul_child = $(html.ul),
                  $li_child = $(html.li);
              var   $span = $(html.span);
              for (var i in n = TreeNodes) {
                  $span.text(n[i].Key);
                  $li_child.append($span);
                  $ul_child.append($li_child);
                  $li_parent.append($ul_child);
                  return recursive(n[i].Nodes, $li_child);
              }
          }
    }
}

var json = '{"data":[{"Nodes":[{"Key":"Root","Nodes":[{"Key":"AAA","Nodes":[{"Key":"BBB","Nodes":[{"Key":"CCC","Nodes":[]}]}]},{"Key":"SubRoot","Nodes":[{"Key":"DDD","Nodes":[{"Key":"EEE","Nodes":[]},{"Key":"FFF","Nodes":[{"Key":"GGG","Nodes":[]}]}]}]}]}]}]}';
var jobj = eval('(' + json + ')');
$('#tree').append(TreeView(jobj));
```

[image]

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `eval` instead of `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: No specific reason

Comment: `eval` has any number of issues that make it very difficult to use effectively.  Might want to avoid it.  See [Why is Using the JavaScript Eval Function a Bad Idea?](/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is pretty simple, and illustrates than one must be careful about details in the code:

in the `recursive` function, when you `return`, it just stops the execution of current function, so when you have more than one node, only the first is processed. Just remove the `return`.

Someone also posted a message and deleted it, but he was right. You also create only one element to append, and you modify it for second node instead of creating another one, so you'll have only the last value displayed. Move the initialisation of the elements to append to the DOM inside the loop.

I also removed the var `n` that seemed useless. (if you used it to copy for not keeping the reference, that won't work, the reference is kept in `n` too)

Change the function to:

```
function recursive(TreeNodes, $li_parent) {
      if (TreeNodes.length > 0) {
          var $ul_child, $li_child, $span, i;
          for (i in TreeNodes) {
              $span = $(html.span);
              $ul_child = $(html.ul);
              $li_child = $(html.li);
              $span.text(TreeNodes[i].Key);
              $li_child.append($span);
              $ul_child.append($li_child);
              $li_parent.append($ul_child);
              recursive(TreeNodes[i].Nodes, $li_child);
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: Using a single span and attempting to `.append` it twice wasn't going to work, but it wasn't the cause of the problem - so not a correct answer.  (Neither are using the same name for variables in multiple scopes as well as for object members, arbitrarily prefixing some of your variable names with "$", and capitalizing variable names)

Comment: I just corrected the OP's code specific problems that made it not working.. Even if i tend to agree with you in what you say, variable naming is more an opinion-based topic, so i kept it as it was